# Disc brake pad release allen bolt

Tags: disc-brake, bolt

I have an Tektro Auriga Comp Hydraulic Disc Brake System. It's been running worry free for ~10 years.

But now I need to replace the rear disk brake pads (for only the second time). However the 3mm allen key holding the pads in place had rounded off. i.e. Meaning I could not take it out with an allen key. Instead I had to drill it out with a bolt extractor.

I'll need to replace this bolt but I'm not sure what it's called.

[image]

Does anyone know the name of this bolt? Alternatively can it be replaced by a different type of bolt?

Comment: I’m amazed you only needed to replace the pads twice in 10 years.

Comment: I would have expected to change them more. I also expected to change the Hydraulic brake oil every 2 years. But I've never needed to do that. When the brakes felt sponge I checked the pads, noticed they were low, replaced them, and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Technically you do really need to replace the fluid through a proper bleed process after 10 years. Tektro uses mineral oil I believe which does not absorb moisture. This means there is likely some water sitting in your calipers which will boil if you get in a heavy braking situation an heat the calipers up a lot. Personally I'd have them bled for peace of mind.

Comment: I was unaware of that. I assumed I'd feel the difference. I already have the parts and it looks fun to do. Good suggestion.

Comment: As there is no load on the pin, you could use a split pin for retaining the pads. (Many brakes do, some Shimano come with a split pin but have threads in the caliper for a retaining bolt)

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. Initially thought that I could replace it with the appropriate part. At $4 it seemed reasonable. But I did not notice the $50 delivery charge. Split Pin it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is generally called a "brake pad retaining bolt" or often only "retaining bolt". They differ between brake brands and sometimes models, but a quick search for your brake model and "retaining bolt" usually turns up the right part.

Comment: Thank you - google immediately gets promising looking results with "brake pad retaining bolt". Thinking about it I could possible also switch over to a clip based solution.

Comment: Looks like this might be the right option - https://www.tektro-usa.com/category.php?catid=187&productid=1220

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to get the correct part from Tektro. I believe Tektro calls those bolts a ‘pad axle’. They have a parts list pdf that you can download from their website.
If you can’t find your model calipers there you can probably find a contact email address or phone number.